# nginx - Google Analytics not showing what video .mp4 our users are viewing

Tags: google-analytics, nginx

Right now I am doing the following with nginx to implement a global rule set for Google Analytics to load on pages.

/etc/nginx/conf.d/analytics.conf

```
sub_filter '</head>' '<script type="text/javascript">var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-99999999-9"]);_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);(function() {var ga = document.createElement("script"); ga.type = "text/javascript"; ga.async = true;ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();</script></head>';
```

Replacing `UA-99999999-9` with my UA ID

However in Google analytics this does not show what video people are watching. Just the page they are on. We are hosting video files in a subfolder with no index file just like this

```
example.com/video1.mp4
example.com/video2.mp4
```

Analytics just shows the user browsing `example.com`

How are we able to see what the `.mp4` file each user is viewing?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? That the video filename would be part of the page path, or something else?

Comment: Google analytics only tracks URLs on which the snippet can be included.   That means HTML files only.  It won't track video, images, scripts, or redirects.